# Mikrotik интерфейсы в режиме switch

Tags: mikrotik

Принимаем untaget трафик от провайдера в eth0, на интерфейсе eth1 повесить два vlan (10 - uplink, 100-internal)
 Задача, чтобы в eth0 и vlan10 не имели доступ к микротику, на микротике только внутренний ip, маршрутизатор другое оборудование подключеное к eth1

Можно прописать правили в Firewall для входного интерфейса, но может есть вариант отключить менеджмент сеть на интерфейсах?

Answer (score 0):

eth0 и vlan10 в бридже? тогда просто не устанавливай ip адрес на этих интерфейсах.

mactelnet отключается в списке в interfaces/ interface list